# What is the order of the number of significantly scattered particles in Møller scattering?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

in an electron-electron collision with a low speed and in the nonrelativistic case, approximately what fraction of electrons get significantly deflected (say more than 10 degrees)? Generally, with increasing the speed of the colliding electrons, does the number of not-deviated (reflected at 180 degrees) particles increase or decrease?

Comment: G.Smith i meant electrons, edited it.

Comment: Being reflected at 180 degrees is the maximum deviation possible, not the not-deviated case.

Comment: G.Smith what is the range of the diffraction angle? And what fraction are defelcted at 180 in the case I deacribed (a lot or a few, what are angles with the most probability)?

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said. Since these are identical particles, you can’t tell whether they both turned around 180 degrees or they just kept going with no deflection. I guess the maximum deflection is 90 degrees.

Comment: The $1/\sin^4{\theta}$ means that angles near 0 and 180 are much more probable than near 90.

Comment: Just plot the function of $\theta$ to see the angular distribution. It will diverge at 0 and 180 degrees because most collisions produce little deflection.

Comment: G.Smith i have plotted it, and my question was about how-to interpret this. Because of the divergence it should be deduced that all electrons are deflected at 0 or 180? How do I know, for example what fraction get defelcted at 10 deg or more for a certain velocity for both electrons?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that all electrons are deflected at 0 or 180.

Comment: Cross sections are only meaningful for a *beam* of electrons colliding with various impact parameters (i.e., how far apart they would pass each other if they didn’t interact.)

Comment: When colliding two beams of electrons, the angular dependence of the differential cross section will tell you how the number deflected through one angle compares with the number deflected through another angle.

Comment: Thanks. What if i have two atoms (like two bound states) colkiding, what kind of scattering would that be? Does it still have such a behavior?

Comment: @G.Smith take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exy2twNRhzQ and the previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not into YouTube physics. If you can make beams of particles (nuclei or atoms included) you can collide them, see what scattering happens, and talk about the differential cross section of the interaction.

Comment: If you haven’t read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)#Differential_cross_section, you should do so to understand how a differential cross section is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Nonrelativistic Møller scattering reduces to Rutherford scattering (plus exchange scattering) in the relative coordinate, and the Rutherford cross sections diverges for small deflection angles.  All incoming particles are, to a greater or lesser extent, scattered.  That means that it is not possible to talk quantitatively about the *fraction* of the total particles scattered through at lease some minimal angle, because there are an infinite number scattered by very small angles $\theta\gtrsim0$.

Comment: So you mean, if I have two electrons colliding with a certain velocity v, it's impossible to calculate the probabikity that the deflection angle is more than a certain amount?

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to ask about this probability. Suppose they both have velocity $0.1c$ in the center-of-momentum frame. If they have an impact parameter of $10^{-10}$ meters, they are going to scatter through larger angles than if they have an impact parameter of $10^{-5}$ meters. This is why cross sections are about scattering of beams with a wide distribution of impact parameters.

Comment: @Ali Lavasani if you have a cutoff then you can certainly calculate it. But if you want to know how many electrons will be "deviated" by any amount then the answer is all of them. An electron on the moon and another on the sun will cause "deviations" to each other because the Coulomb force has infinite range.

Comment: @G.Smith does the probability for larger scattering angles increase or decrease as the velocity of incidence increases?

Comment: @KFGauss what kind of scattering is the collision between two atoms? Does it have the same behavior as moller scattering?

Comment: In the formula for Moller scattering, you can see that the probability of scattering at any angle decreases as the velocity increases. I don’t think atom-atom scattering has a special name, and I don’t know much about it. The differential cross section would not be the same as for Moller scattering, but I would expect it to similarly decrease with angle and decrease with velocity.

Comment: @G.Smith and what about very low collision speeds (say 1 m/s)? Do scattering formulas still apply? What's the difference?

Comment: As far as I know, scattering formulas apply at very low speeds. Of course, in Moller scattering, you would have to use either the exact formula or its nonrelativistic limit, not its ultrarelativistic limit.